# libssh2: `libssh2_channel_forward_listen_ex` returning "Unable to send global-request packet"

Tags: openssh, libssh2

I am trying to do local port forwarding with libssh2.

I have a server (docker container) with openssh running a TCP echo service. I am using password login. I can `ssh` into the machine fine. I am able to use `ssh -L 7894:127.0.0.1:1794 server` to do port forwarding and the echo service works fine echoing back to netcat run with `nc 127.0.0.1 7894` from my machine.

I am trying to write an application that uses `libssh2` to replicate the above access to the TCP echo server.

`libssh2_channel_forward_listen_ex` fails with the error string set to "Unable to send global-request packet for forward listen request" and errno set to -7.

I have debugging enabled on openssh. Here is the tail of the log

```
2022-10-26 13:48:02.221353473  Accepted password for linuxserver.io from 172.17.0.1 port 59038 ssh2
2022-10-26 13:48:02.221354712  debug1: monitor_child_preauth: user linuxserver.io authenticated by privileged process
2022-10-26 13:48:02.221355826  debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
2022-10-26 13:48:02.221356944  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 26
2022-10-26 13:48:02.221358009  debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
2022-10-26 13:48:02.225893485  debug3: mm_get_keystate: GOT new keys
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226000913  debug3: mm_auth_password: user authenticated [preauth]
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226070905  debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226164806  debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 3.936ms, delaying 4.139ms (requested 8.076ms) [preauth]
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226271865  debug3: send packet: type 52 [preauth]
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226375237  debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 26 [preauth]
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226423116  debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state [preauth]
2022-10-26 13:48:02.226827341  debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
2022-10-26 13:48:02.227487840  debug3: ssh_sandbox_parent_finish: finished
2022-10-26 13:48:02.228021181  User child is on pid 266
2022-10-26 13:48:02.228839803  debug3: monitor_apply_keystate: packet_set_state
2022-10-26 13:48:02.229331154  debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
2022-10-26 13:48:02.229740053  debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
2022-10-26 13:48:02.230150994  debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
2022-10-26 13:48:02.230567267  debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
2022-10-26 13:48:02.231008444  debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
2022-10-26 13:48:02.231441309  debug3: ssh_packet_set_state: done
2022-10-26 13:48:02.231937248  debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 0: ssh-rsa SHA256:/7FFzlIP6gEuh52lzVrSDATTQFj4wnH5ScMtaH+NpHM
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232015182  debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:njZFCzAT2OFVE0n/kJ6YdOVCF7iPGjyZmy5Lr+3DE2E
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232069432  debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:YP702pqTQF410dCkQgOsWD/pz+MXoVNv5EzQnxklFD4
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232091834  debug3: notify_hostkeys: sent 3 hostkeys
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232108621  debug3: send packet: type 80
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232146882  debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232166314  debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232183856  debug1: server_init_dispatch
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232393938  Connection closed by 172.17.0.1 port 59038
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232422452  debug1: do_cleanup
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232439029  Transferred: sent 2096, received 1368 bytes
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232453748  Closing connection to 172.17.0.1 port 59038
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232524366  debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 50
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232582535  debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232583894  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 50
2022-10-26 13:48:02.232585103  debug3: mm_answer_term: tearing down sessions
```

I also enabled debug tracing in `libssh2`. Here is the output from my application:

```
[libssh2] 0.225733 Conn: Requesting tcpip-forward session for 127.0.0.1:54814
[2022-10-26 08:48:02.226] [error] Failed to start the local-forward listener: Unable to send global-request packet for forward listen request (-7)

=> libssh2_transport_write plain (36 bytes)
0000: 50 00 00 00 0D 74 63 70  69 70 2D 66 6F 72 77 61 : P....tcpip-forwa
0010: 72 64 01 00 00 00 09 31  32 37 2E 30 2E 30 2E 31 : rd.....127.0.0.1
0020: 00 00 D6 1E                                      : ....
[libssh2] 0.225763 Socket: Error sending 80 bytes: 9
[libssh2] 0.225765 Failure Event: -7 - Unable to send global-request packet for forward listen request
[libssh2] 0.225935 Transport: Disconnecting: reason=11, desc=Shutdown SSH session, lang=
=> libssh2_transport_write plain (33 bytes)
0000: 01 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00  14 53 68 75 74 64 6F 77 : .........Shutdow
0010: 6E 20 53 53 48 20 73 65  73 73 69 6F 6E 00 00 00 : n SSH session...
0020: 00                                               : .
=> libssh2_transport_write plain2 (0 bytes)
[libssh2] 0.225977 Socket: Error sending 80 bytes: 9
[libssh2] 0.225979 Transport: Freeing session resource
[libssh2] 0.225985 Transport: Extra packets left 0
[libssh2] 0.225987 Transport: unable to reset socket's blocking state

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this!

**Update:**
Looks like `Socket: Error sending 80 bytes: 9` is indicating a timeout error.  I've tried adding `libssh2_session_set_timeout(session, 0);` but it did nothing.

Comment: Not surprisingly, it was user error. I tried to get too fancy with an RAII class for sockets and got bit.  The interesting part was that the error was up in the handshake (wrong value for socket) yet it didn't report an error until it got down to the `libssh2_channel_forward_listen_ex` call.

I am closing this since the error is not shown in the presenting code. I will leave the question up though since some of the troubleshooting steps might be useful to someone.